How To link custom fonts in function.php file
I'm Trying to add custom fonts in my WordPress development theme, but I got fatal error here how I add it
/// Register fonts.
    Wp_register_style('font-awesome', get_stylesheet_uri(), [], filemtime get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/font-awesome-webfont.woff', [], false, 'all');
    wp_register_style('Naskh', get_stylesheet_uri(), [], filemtime get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/naskh-webfont.woff', [], false, 'all');
    wp_register_style('Roboto', get_stylesheet_uri(), [], filemtime, get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/roboto-webfont.woff', [], false, 'all');`


`/// Enqueue Fonts.
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-webfont.woff');
    wp_enqueue_style('naskh-webfont.woff');
    wp_enqueue_style('roboto-webfont.woff');`

and in the css i add it like this

`--arabic-fonts:src='\\fonts\\naskh-webfont.woff';
--english-fonts:src='\\fonts\\roboto-webfont.woff';`

`[dir="rtl"] .container {font-family:var(--arabic-fonts);}
[dir="ltr"] .container {font-family:var(--english-fonts);}`

Please help me Thanks For Your Reply I appreciate it
I tried Google It But Could Not Found Any Possible Fix
here the error that i got and sorry

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "filemtime" in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-content\themes\Copper\functions.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324):
copper_enqueue_scripts('')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\script-loader.php(2265): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_enqueue_scripts('')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\general-template.php(3050): do_action('wp_head')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-content\themes\Copper\header.php(13): wp_head()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\template.php(810): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\template.php(745): load_template('C:\xampp\htdocs...', true, Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-content\themes\Copper\index.php(7): get_header()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#16 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebSite\wp-content\themes\Copper\functions.php on line 16
There has been a critical error on this website.

and the problem is that VS Code doesn't show any error in the editor

You forgot to tell us what error you got, or on what line. Please [edit] your question

Is this a PHP problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem? The code you've shared does not look like valid PHP after all, unless you defined the constant filemtime anywhere (which you probably didn't, as the error message told you)

Hi, this is PHP problem because it's PHP file named function.php, and I'm trying to add fonts style to my default theme that I want to create Thanks for your reply and help Thanks

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Hi How to do that please tell me

When you use word without $ like here filemtime PHP treat it like a CONSTANT, so you need to defined it first.
The fourth argument of this function defined version of your script. You can set there FALSE (which is default behaviour) or defined the constant first. For example on the top of your file where you try to put this code:
define('VERSION', '1.0.0' );
then
wp_register_style('Naskh', get_stylesheet_uri(), [], VERSION, get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/naskh-webfont.woff', [], false, 'all');


Hi, thank you very much for your reply now that the code is working I want to know how to write it in CSS style file like this,  --arabic-fonts:Naskh; and call it like this font-family:var--(arabic-fonts); or I'm writing it false please help me THANKS

You used the filemtime function incorrectly.
Try this:
// Register fonts.
wp_register_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/font-awesome-webfont.woff', [], filemtime(get_template_directory().'/fonts/font-awesome-webfont.woff'), 'all');
wp_register_style('Naskh', get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/naskh-webfont.woff', [], filemtime(get_template_directory().'/fonts/naskh-webfont.woff'), 'all');
wp_register_style('Roboto', get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/roboto-webfont.woff', [], filemtime(get_template_directory().'/fonts/roboto-webfont.woff'), 'all');

// Enqueue Fonts.
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome');
wp_enqueue_style('Naskh');
wp_enqueue_style('Roboto');

And for the CSS, use url instead of using src. Use the correct path to your file and remove unnecessary backslashes:
:root {
  --arabic-fonts: url('/fonts/naskh-webfont.woff');
  --english-fonts: url('/fonts/roboto-webfont.woff');
}

[dir="rtl"] .container {
  font-family: var(--arabic-fonts);
}

[dir="ltr"] .container {
  font-family: var(--english-fonts);
}


Enqueue styles in wordpress

you need to wrap wp_enqueue_style() in a function and call this function via add_action()
Wordpress wp_enqueue_style() expects a CSS file – not a font file .
See the official codex doc.

You don't necessarily need to register the stylesheet before via wp_register_style()
Here is a simplified version for the functions.php

function add_custom_stylesheet()
{

    $version = filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/fonts.css');
    $dependencies = array();
    wp_enqueue_style('local-fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts.css', $dependencies, $version, 'all');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_stylesheet');


Wordpress will add a <link> element to the <head> HTML output referencing CSS file fonts.css (stored in your theme directory).
<link rel='stylesheet' id='local-fonts-css' href='https://your-domain.com/wp-content/your-theme/copper/fonts.css?ver=1660338149' type='text/css' media='all' />

CSS file: specify fonts
The CSS file needs to contain a @font-face rule for every font-family.
This is not specific to Wordpress. Basically you just add the stylesheet. The actual font loading is done in CSS.
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Naskh';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('fonts/naskh-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('fonts/roboto-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    }

    :root {
        --arabic-fonts: 'Naskh';
        --english-fonts: 'Roboto';
    }


    /* apply fonts to elements */

    [dir="rtl"] .container {
        font-family: var(--arabic-fonts);
    }

    [dir="ltr"] .container {
        font-family: var(--english-fonts);
    }


Save your font files in a folder named fonts in your theme directory.
Cache busting via filemtime()` based CSS suffix
You don't necessarily need the filemtime() (returning a unix timestamp of your file modified age) – this is just a common cache busting technique. This can be handy if you're still frequently updating your theme.
Once you've completed the theming you can just add a static number like 1.0.0. In fact I'd rather recommend to ditch the version completely for a cached CSS file or used independently versioned themes (or child-themes) so can can easily roll back to a previous version (mytheme11 to mytheme10)
See also "How to use wp_enqueue_style() in my WordPress theme?"
